# JS Jasmine's `beforeEach` not waiting before running the test

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor

I am new to Protractor and Jasmine, i have encountered this issue while writing my first test:

```
    describe('Test suite for gui', () => {
    let page: GuiPage;

        beforeEach(async () => {
            page = new GuiPage();
            console.log(`GuiPage object status before each:${page}`);
            await page.login();
        });
    it('First test', async () => {
            console.log(`GuiPage object status first test: ${page}`);
            page.invokeSomeMethod();
    }
}
```

The output:

```
GuiPage object status first test: undefined
Cannot read property 'invokeSomeMethod' of undefined
....a long stacktrace....
GuiPage object status before each:[object Object]
```

So, clearly it seems like the test itself is invoked before the call to `beforeEach` is completed.
In the protractor config file i have:

```
exports.config = {
.....many other non relevant configs....
  onPrepare() {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 240000;
  }
};
```

Is there anything visibly wrong in my test?

Comment: Could you provide your code for GuiPage? It looks like there is probably some race condition between your constructor with some async call and your console log. How you could check this? Add an `await new Promise(resolve => { setTimeout(resolve, 1000); });` right after your constructor (exact syntax might not be correct).  If that is the case, you should move your async calls out of your constructor of GuiPage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have faced a situation similar to this and it was frustrating. I think it might depend on the version of Jasmine you're on (older version you will experience this I think).

Regardless, I did this to fix it:

```
// add done call back
beforeEach(async (done: DoneFn) => {
            page = new GuiPage();
            console.log(`GuiPage object status before each:${page}`);
            await page.login();
            // call done to let jasmine know we are done with this function
            done();
        });
```

Hopefully, the above will fix it.

Comment: Frustrating indeed. I was banging my head against a wall for 2 hours until I found your answer. Thank you! Incidentally, I'm using jasmine-node 3.0.0, which in many cases behaves like an old version of jasmine.